# Distance Value from RavenDB Spatial query

Tags: ravendb, geospatial

Is there a way to get the distance calculation value from RavenDB when doing a spatial search.    I tried converting the suggested
     _ = SpatialIndex.Generate(r.Latitude, r.Longitude) 
to
     distance = SpatialIndex.Generate(r.Latitude, r.Longitude)

Did not get a value back.

Our goal is to show the distance in miles on our web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric,
You have the long & lat, you can just do the math in memory.